# Confused about which impedence value to pick for ferrite bead

Tags: impedance, ferrite, ferrite-bead

Per the vendor's recommendation, I need to add a ferrite bead to the 2.5 V power supply. An evaluation board used the BLM31PG601SN1. It has an impedance of 600 Ω at 100 MHz and a rated current of 1500 mA.

I wanted to get something comparable for a newer design for space applications, but wasn't too sure of how to choose the proper impedance. I know you would like to be resistive at your board frequency but how do I determine if I need a 600 Ω or a 200 Ω ferrite bead.

What calculations would I have to do?

Comment: What power supply, what load, how much filtering is needed (attenuation at frequencies), and what load (V, I and how much does it vary over operating conditions)?

Comment: Why not use the BLM31PG601SN1? Surely it is comparable because it's what the eval board uses?

Comment: Its a commercial device. I need a space grade device

Comment: Look at the actual impedance curves for the device in question.  It's crazy that beads are always rated at 100MHZ.

Comment: https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/tools/wirewound-ferrite-bead-finder/#/search

Answer (score 1):

A ferrite bead acts kind of like a frequency-dependent resistor. While inductors and capacitors have a similar effect of changing impedance over frequency, a ferrite bead dissipates the high frequency currents as heat, like a resistor does, instead of storing energy.

This is useful for impeding the flow of high frequency currents, e.g. for EMI and noise reasons. The currents in the circuit will take the path of lowest impedance, so if you want to keep them local then you have two primary options: offer them a lower impedance path (e.g. a decoupling capacitor) nearby, or increase the impedance of the path you don't want them to take.

In a lot of cases you can just place a decoupling capacitor near the load, with short traces to keep the parasitic inductance low, and a ground reference plane underneath. When that is insufficient (e.g. if the high frequency currents are quite large) you might add a ferrite bead to help prevent the high frequency currents from propagating to undesirable areas of the circuit.

If you think about how this looks in a circuit, you might see something familiar:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdZHW1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is essentially an RC low pass filter.

The problem with RC low pass filters in power delivery contexts is that you're putting a resistor in series with your load, which inherently limits the current and causes voltage drops and power dissipation as the current rises. The cutoff frequency of the filter increases as the resistance decreases, so you get less attenuation of high frequency currents for a given capacitance. If you try to compensate by making the capacitance larger and larger, the ESR (and high frequency impedance) of the capacitors increases making the filter less and less effective.

Since a ferrite bead has low impedance at DC and low frequency, and high impedance at high frequency AC, it is ideal for this job. The DC and low frequency currents are relatively unimpeded by the ferrite bead. The high frequency currents are filtered as essentially if they were going through an RC filter - one with a resistance equal to the impedance of the ferrite bead at the given frequency.

To design this type of filter you take a look at the datasheet. It will tell you what the resistance at DC is, and what the current rating is. The datasheet usually lists the bead's high frequency impedance as \$|Z|\$ at 100MHz, but there will also be a graph of impedance vs. frequency, sometimes as a "ZRX plot" with three lines: impedance (Z), resistance (R), reactance (X).

The resistance at DC will tell you what the voltage drop will be for your load current, i.e. \$V=IR\$, and also the power dissipation that will occur at DC, i.e. \$P=I^2R\$. You can use this to figure out if your ferrite bead is suitably rated for the current.

After that, you find the impedance at the frequency you want to filter out, and figure out how much attenuation (in dB) you'll get at that frequency. The calculations are essentially the same as for an RC low pass, except that R changes for each frequency. You'll then also need to simulate or measure the magnitude of the high frequency portion of the currents, and use that to figure out the power dissipation in the ferrite.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I am still confused about the impedance that s spec'd at 100MHz, like 600 ohms in one case and 200 ohms in another part. If all other parameters being equal and the DC resistance is acceptable as well as the current rating, how do I decide which one is better suited for me?

Comment: @Matty The impedance at 100MHz is just a convenient single number to tell you the rough magnitude of the impedance of the part, so it can be searched for in parametric searches. You need to look at the impedance vs. frequency graphs in the datasheets to know what their exact impedance will be at the frequency you care about. As for how high an impedance you need, that depends on all sorts of things. Generally speaking you want it as high as possible at the frequencies you want to attenuate while keeping it low as possible at low frequencies and DC.

Comment: @Matty If you're copying an existing design but need to change the part for some other reason, e.g. due to industrial compliance or an environmental specification, you find the impedance at the fundamental frequency of the load (e.g. the switching frequency if it's an SMPS, or the frequency of the rise/fall rate if it's digital logic), then look at the datasheet for the existing ferrite bead to find what the impedance is at that frequency and what the DC resistance is, and use those numbers to evaluate other ferrite beads that meet your requirements.

Comment: Note that impedance drops precipitously under DC bias, even just 10s of mA for smaller chip beads. The impedance can usually be treated linearly for small signals, i.e. filtering analog and logic level signals, low levels of ambient EMI; but they will saturate (drop to a low incremental impedance) under large signals such as EFT/ESD, or under supply bypass.

Comment: @TimWilliams I hadn't realised the DC bias was quite so critical. Are the ZRX plots usually specified at a specific bias?

Comment: @Polynomial Yes, 0mA. Some manufacturers provide a series of curves, e.g. Laird. Bias handling scales more or less with chip size, so 0402s and below might suffer from 10s of mA, especially in high Z's; 1206s typically handle 100-200mA; etc. (For some amperes of filtering, better to use an inductor proper, and add dampening as needed.)